# What does the numerator in requests of network tab on Chrome represent?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

This probably is a simple answer but it doesn't seem to be documented. I'll just post the image of what I'm talking about here.

[image]

What's the highlighted number supposed to be? Number of 40 subsequent requests made as opposed to 145 requests random requests?

Comment: Good question, I only see one number there.

Comment: My guess is that it refers to requests that have been completed out of requests that have been sent. So you've sent 145 requests, and received responses to 40 of them.

Comment: @Barmar I'm using Windows Chrome 37 Stable build. It doesn't appear to be in Canary build.

Comment: I'm also using Chrome 37.

Comment: P.S. Please make use of SO's name completion after `@` so that you spell names correctly. There's no `e` in my name.

Comment: Oops, fixed. And I'm an idiot. It's when you set the filters on. Tells you that number of requests out of total. So, if you filter it with XHR then 40 / 145 requests means 40 XHR requests.

Comment: Post that as an answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noticed by @Barmar, the highlighted number was not displaying on his end so I started looking for any extensions or settings that might have caused this and immediately found that I had my filters on in the Network Tab.
As mentioned in the comment above if you have `XHR` filter on in Network tab then 40/145 requests means that 40 of the requests were `XHR` out of 145.